# How to hide a collapsed element if another one is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 buttons which when clicked collapses and a form is shown. What I want is if one is already collapsed then I want it to hide again if another one is clicked.

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/77soggnv/

This is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //See which panel has been clicked
    $("#citizen").click(function(){
        $(this).data('clicked', true);
    });
    $("#organisation").click(function(){
        $(this).data('clicked', true);
    });
    $("#anonymous").click(function(){
        $(this).data('clicked', true);
    });

    //Hide the other panels if one is clicked
    if($("#citizen").data('clicked')){
        $("#organisation").collapse("hide");
        $("#anonymous").collapse("hide");
    }
    if($("#organisation").data('clicked')){
        $("#citizen").collapse("hide");
        $("#anonymous").collapse("hide");
    }
    if($("#anonymous").data('clicked')){
        $("#organisation").collapse("hide");
        $("#citizen").collapse("hide");
    }    

});
```

Comment: Just use a variable to save your current state so you always know if something was collapsed before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply you can do it like:

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
    $('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
});
```

[***Updated Fiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/77soggnv/3/)

Comment: This was beutiful. One element collapses as the other one hides. Just what I was looking for. What exactly are we doing here though: `$('.collapse.in')` ??

Comment: @FelixRosén _( in )_ it's a CLASS that added when you open collapsed div to identify it as opened. collapsed div has (.collapse) class, opened div has ( .collapse .in ), in this way we force collapsing all opened div before opening current.

Answer (score 0):

Since the clicking elements have common classnames and structure, we don't have to attach event separately.

```
$(".btn.btn-primary").click(function() {
  var next = $(this).next();
  $(".collapse").not(next).slideUp();
  next.slideToggle();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/77soggnv/2/)

`next()` method will return the element after the current element.

Comment: That seems to work. But I dont really understand what you are doing here though.

Comment: @FelixRosén check now.